# Moving file in Ruby using move command

Tags: ruby

I am trying to do a very simple `mv` command. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the below code?

```
src="xyz_*.bak"
dest = "xyz"

FileUtils.mv Dir.glob("#{curr}"+'/'+"#{src}"), "#{dest}"
```

I am seeing the following error:
`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /home/dir/src/lib/util/xyz_abc_1.bak or xyz/xyz_abc_1.bak`

I  double checked and `xyz_abc_1.bak` file exists.

Comment: Where does `curr` come from? Can you provide the directory structure you are working in?

Comment: Does your xyz directory exist?

Comment: I dint have the directory. That is why it was failing. Created one and it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the current directory, there is no requirement to include this, also since all your variables are already strings this can be simplified as well.

A little bit of validation should yield much more useful results.

```
require 'fileutils'
pattern = "my_temp*.bak"
dest = "tmp_dest"
located_files = Dir.glob(pattern)
if located_files.length == 0
     abort("ERROR: Unable to locate files given by #{pattern} in #{Dir.pwd}") 
end

if Dir.exists? dest
    FileUtils.move located_files , dest
else
    abort("ERROR: #{dest} directory does not exist")
end
```